# Where is a list of "Boot flags" available for Parallels Desktop for Mac?

Tags: parallels-desktop

In the need to disable/remove the not configured ata5, ata6, ata7 and ata8 devices, I was looking for a list of available **Boot flags** for **Parallels Desktop for Mac**.

So far I found this list:

```
devices.apic.disable=0 # workaround to run Solaris installation, after installation a pic can be enabled
devices.net.track_link_status=0 # for network link connect/disconnect issues
devices.net.force_adapter_type=rtl # force realtek network adapter
devices.usb.ehc=0 # disable EHCI interface (USB 2.)
devices.usb.enable_mouse=0 # disable virtual mouse
devices.usb.keyboard=0 # disable virtual keyboard
devices.video.pci_device_id=0x5005 # workaround for issue with black screen in Windows 8 with guest tools installed
kernel.waet.enable=0 # disable Windows ACPI Emulated Device Table
video.dx_cmp=0 # workaround for crash if you attempt to go into character customization
video.dx_profile=6 # force Windows 7 Aero compatibility at the cost of possible 3D problems
vm.app_mode=32 # set your virtual machine process to run in 32-bit mode
vm.compat_level=2 # workaround for Blue screen of Death STOP 0x7B or System Repair screen
vm.mem_anonymous=0 # workaround for crash with host server 4.0 and guest mac os x server 10.6.5 < 10H574
```

Is there a more complete list of (all) "Boot flags" available for "Parallels Desktop for Mac"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That list is very helpful! Some more options, but without comments or context, can be found like this:

```
pcregrep --buffer-size 512000 -e "\\x00((?:[a-z0-9-_]+\\.)+[a-z0-9-_]+)\\x00" -o --text /Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Parallels\ VM.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_vm_app
```

Or *sorted* and *limited* to device, kernel, video and vm:

`pcregrep --buffer-size 2M -e "\\x00((devices\\.|kernel\\.|video\\.|vm\\.)+(?:[a-z0-9-_]+\\.)+[a-z0-9-_]+)\\x00" -o --text /Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Parallels\ VM.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_vm_app | sort`

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. Note that `--buffer-size 2M` will suppress the "is too long for the internal buffer" error for a 29M sized `/prl_vm_app`. The answer will be more helpfull if there is a command that does not output the irrelevant strings. Like a filter for lines that start with `devices.` `kernel.` `video.` or `vm.`.

Comment: I would also like `pcregrep --buffer-size 2M -e "\\x00((devices\\.|kernel\\.|video\\.|vm\\.)+(?:[a-z0-9-_]+\\.)+[a-z0-9-_]+)\\x00" -o --text /Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Parallels\ VM.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_vm_app | sort` for a nicely sorted list of suspects.